# how to POST x-www-form-urlencoded to REST api from swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, rest

I have written the following in order to POST to a REST API I've written in nodejs. However I'm getting no response on the server side.

```
 func login()
{
    let u = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "userIP")!
    let url_to_login = "http://\(u)/users/authenticate"

    let url:URL = URL(string: url_to_login)!

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)

    let postDataString = "tag=name:example@hotmail.co.uk&password:password"
    let postData:NSData = postDataString.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)! as NSData
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = postData as Data
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


    print(url_to_login)

}



//button actions 

@IBAction func Submit(_ sender: UIButton) {

    login()
}
```

This POST should simply send the two tags as a x-www-form-urlencoded and get a token in return. I've POSTED other methods, however, this doesn't give an indication of doing anything on the server side either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not posting anything, you're just setting the content of the request. This request has to be used for posting, this is the next step you have to implement. :)

Comment: @EricAya Understood! Silly mistake on my part. I'm now however, getting authentication failed, am I sending the data in the correct way?

Comment: Please update your question to include _now however, getting authentication failed_ code. No one can check if you are _sending the data in the correct way_ without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you post body looks wrong

instead:

```
let postDataString = "tag=name:example@hotmail.co.uk&password:password"
```

try this:

```
let postDataString = "name=example@hotmail.co.uk&password=password"
```

Note: you send the data as `charset=utf-8` but you convert it as `String.Encoding.ascii`